# Convertor matrices

Tags: commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let us consider $\mathbb{C}^n$, the set of  all $n$-tuples of complex numbers.  We know that $(\mathbb{C}^n,+,\cdot)$ is a unital commutative complex algebra.

Suppose that  $\diamond$ is an associative multiplication on  ($\mathbb{C}^n,+$) such that $(\mathbb{C}^n,+,\diamond)$ forms a unital commutative complex algebra.

**Q.** Suppose that $A:(\mathbb{C}^n,+,\diamond) \to (\mathbb{C}^n,+,\cdot)$ is a unital homomorphism. Is $A$ necessary invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The map $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^2$ (with componentwise operations both times), $(z,w)\mapsto (z,z)$ is a counterexample.

Of course, this is just the projection map $\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb C^1$ in mild disguise.